# Isabelle: degree of polynomial multiplied with constant

Tags: polynomial-math, isabelle

I am working with the library `HOL/Library/Polynomial.thy`.

A simple property didn't work. E.g., the degree of `2x *2` is equal to the degree of `2x`-

How can I prove the lemmas (i.e., remove "sorry"):

```
lemma mylemma:
    fixes y ::  "('a::comm_ring_1 poly)" and x ::  "('a::comm_ring_1)"
    shows "1 = 1" (* dummy *)
 proof- 
 have "⋀ x. degree [: x :] = 0" by simp

 from this have "⋀ x y. degree (y * [: x :] ) = degree y" sorry

 (* different notation: *)
 from this have "⋀ x y. degree (y * (CONST pCons x 0)) = degree y" sorry
```

.

**From Manuel's answer, the solution I was looking for:**

```
 have 1: "⋀ x. degree [: x :] = 0" by simp
 {
   fix y :: "('a::comm_ring_1 poly)" and x :: "('a::comm_ring_1)"
   from 1 have "degree (y * [: x :]) ≤ degree y"
   by (metis Nat.add_0_right degree_mult_le)
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues here.

First of all, the statement you are trying to show simply does not hold for all `x`. If `x = 0` and `y` is nonconstant, e.g. `y = [:0,1:]`, you have

```
degree (y * [: x :]) = degree 0 = 0 ≠ 1 = degree y
```

The obvious way to fix this is to assume `x ≠ 0`.

However, this is not sufficient either, since you only assumed `'a` to be a commutative ring. However, in a commutative ring, in general, you can have zero divisors. Consider the commutative ring `ℤ/4ℤ`. Let `x = 2` and `y = [:0,2:]`.
Then `y * [:x:] = [:0,4:]`, but `4 = 0` in `ℤ/4ℤ`. Therefore `y * [:x:] = 0`, and therefore, again,

```
degree (y * [: x :]) = degree 0 = 0 ≠ 1 = degree y
```

So, what you really need is one of the following two:

1. the assumption `x ≠ 0` and 'a::idom instead of 'a::comm_ring. idom stands for “integral domain” and, that is simply a commutative ring with a 1 and without zero divisors
2. more generally, the assumption that `x` is not a zero divisor
3. even more generally, the assumption that `x * y ≠ 0` or, equivalently, `x` times the leading coefficient of y is not 0

Also, the usage of ⋀ in Isar proofs is somewhat problematic at times. The “proper“ Isar way of doing this would be:

```
fix x :: "'a::idom" and y :: "'a poly"
assume "x ≠ 0"
hence "degree (y * [:x:]) = degree y" by simp
```

The relevant lemmas are `degree_mult_eq` and `degree_smult_eq`, you will see that they require the coefficient type to be an idom. This works for the first case I described above, the other two will require some more manual reasoning, I think.

EDIT: just a small hint: you can find theorems like this by typing

```
find_theorems "degree (_ * _)"
```

If you try to apply the `degree_mult_eq` it shows to your situation (with comm_ring), you will find that it fails, even though the terms seem to match. If that is the case, it is usually a type issue, so you can write something like

```
from [[show_sorts]] degree_mult_eq
```

to see what the types and sorts required by the lemma are, and it says `idom`.

Comment: Thanks for your super answer. Indeed, "<= degree y" is enough for my proof.

Comment: In that case, I sugest degree_mult_le, which even works on commutative semirings.